# Join 3 tables when one doesn't have value

Tags: sql, select, join

I'm trying to join 3 tables that hold values for users - their id and username, and table `engine4_storage_files` that has info about users profile picture. If user hasn't uploaded it's profile pic, there isn't a record in `sf` table - but I want to query all users regardless of weather the pic is uploaded or not.

```
SELECT p.user_id as gledalac, sf.storage_path, 
       u.displayname, u.username
FROM engine4_pregledi p JOIN 
     engine4_storage_files sf JOIN 
     engine4_users u
WHERE p.subject_id = 1
AND   p.user_id = u.user_id
AND   sf.parent_id = u.user_id
AND   sf.parent_type =  'user'
AND   sf.type =  'thumb.icon'
AND   sf.parent_file_id = u.photo_id
order by datum desc limit 10
```

This query returns 3 users with path to their images, but actually there are 4 users to be shown, but 4th user doesn't have profile image - so he's not included in query result.

Is there a way to include 4th user that doesn't have profile image into query results?

Comment: Why not use left join?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `LEFT JOIN` instead,

```
SELECT  p.user_id as gledalac, 
        sf.storage_path, 
        u.displayname, 
        u.username
FROM    engine4_pregledi p 
        LEFT JOIN engine4_users u 
            ON p.user_id = u.user_id
        LEFT JOIN engine4_storage_files sf 
            ON  sf.parent_id = u.user_id AND 
                sf.parent_type =  'user' AND 
                sf.type =  'thumb.icon' AND 
                sf.parent_file_id = u.photo_id
WHERE   p.subject_id = 1 
ORDER   BY datum DESC 
LIMIT   10
```

To fully gain knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: Works like charm, thanks. I sure will check out your link so I don't need to ask these kinds of q's here :)